# Fancybox 2: custom navigation

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm making my own custom navigation for Fancybox 2. Everything is working out just fine, until i bumped on the following problem. The moment my fancybox opens, the arrows are visible and working, but when i click them, they dissapear from the moment the next image shows.

```
$("#portfoliodetail a.detailviewer").fancybox({
    padding: 0,
    helpers:{
        overlay: {
            css: {
                'background': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.84)'
            }
        }
    },
    afterShow: function() {
        $("#detailviewernav").appendTo(".fancybox-wrap");
        $("#detailviewernav").show();
    },
    afterClose: function() {
        $("#detailviewernav").hide();
    }
});

$('#detailviewerprev').click(function(){
  $.fancybox.prev();
});

$('#detailviewernext').click(function(){
  $.fancybox.next();
});

function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel) {
   $('#mycarousel-next').bind('click', function() {
       carousel.next();
       return false;
   });

   $('#mycarousel-prev').bind('click', function() {
       carousel.prev();
       return false;
   });
};
```

As you can see, the 'detailviewernav' div is my custom navigation which i show & hide when the gallery is being opened. I append it to the fancybox_wrap class.

Any idea how i should solve this?

Cheers!

Edit: I added a JSFiddle! http://jsfiddle.net/J2eHp/1/

Comment: Could you toss this into a jsFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

### Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryVfD/3/)

---

There's a couple of things wrong. First is that this line

```
$("#detailviewernav").appendTo(".fancybox-wrap");
```

You're actually moving the element from its position in the dom initially and appending it to `.fancybox-wrap`. The problem with that is once the next image loads, it loads inside `.fancybox-wrap` and when your code executes that line again, there isn't a `#detailviewernav` in the DOM anymore.

So you can swap it to with

```
$("#detailviewernav").clone().appendTo(".fancybox-wrap");
```

to clone it before moving it so that you have access to it again. (You might want to use a class instead of an ID so that you don't end up with multiple elements with the same IDs.

The second thing is since the DOM is being manipulated, you'll need to delegate the events.

```
$('body').on('click','.fancybox-wrap #detailviewerprev',function(){
        $.fancybox.prev();
    });

    $('body').on('click','.fancybox-wrap #detailviewernext',function(){
      $.fancybox.next();
    });
```

Comment: To avoid unnecessary propagation, better target the parent of the nav buttons `$('.fancybox-wrap').on('click',' #detailviewerprev',function()...` and `$('.fancybox-wrap').on('click',' #detailviewernext',function()...`; it can actually be done within the `beforeShow` callback

Comment: This works beautifully, thank you very much Amin! Explained very well too, i hadn't used the clone function before.