# fancyBox v2: Custom button navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

I have almost the same question as here: [Fancybox 2: custom navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607600/fancybox-2-custom-navigation)

I need a custom navigation just like the example from fancyBox with custom buttons: http://jsfiddle.net/deseA/100/

Just that, the buttons are above the image. But when I append the menu to `fancybox-inner`, the links are gone when I click the next image. I tried the solution from the mentioned post, but it doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    nextEffect  : 'fade',
    prevEffect  : 'fade',
    padding     : 0,
    margin      : [15, 15, 40, 15],
    afterLoad   : addLinks,
    beforeClose : removeLinks
});

function addLinks() {
    var list = $("#links");

    if (!list.length) {    
        list = $('<ul id="links">');

        for (var i = 0; i < this.group.length; i++) {
            $('<li data-index="' + i + '"><label></label></li>')
                .click(function() { $.fancybox.jumpto($(this).data('index')); })
                .appendTo(list);
        }

        list.appendTo('.fancybox-inner');
    }

    list.find('li').removeClass('active').eq(this.index).addClass('active');
}

function removeLinks() {
    $("#links").remove();    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to move the line `list.appendTo('.fancybox-inner');` out from the `if` statement. So, the `function addLinks()` would look like this:

```
function addLinks() {
    var list = $("#links");

    if (!list.length) {
        list = $('<ul id="links">');

        for (var i = 0; i < this.group.length; i++) {
            $('<li data-index="' + i + '"><label></label></li>')
                .click(function() { $.fancybox.jumpto($(this).data('index')); })
                .appendTo(list);
        }
    }

    list.appendTo('.fancybox-inner');
    list.find('li').removeClass('active').eq(this.index).addClass('active');
}
```